# react-chartjs2 manage max value

Tags: reactjs, chartjs-2.6.0

[image]

There is my chartjs2 horizontal bar chart.
I want to manage max value.

If you see second chart, max value is 14, and min value is 13.
I want to manage the max and min gap.
I mean, I want the second chart to display   x-coordinate's min value is 10 and max is more 14.(probably 15 or 16)
Also I don't want to show cut the data label.
The max value label is cut. 14

I tried to max value plus some rest value, but it was not good.
;(

Pleas give your ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed option which is align property.

```
plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          align: 'top',
          anchor: 'end',
          color: 'rgb(16,0,0)'
        }
      }
```